# Why is false && false || true evaluated to true?

Tags: boolean-expression, short-circuiting

I understood that in short-circuit valuation if the initial value is `false` followed by an `&&` then the expression short-circuits and the expression is evaluated to `false`.

Surely the statement `false && false || true` should evaluate to `false`, but in it always evaluates to `true`. I would have thought that the `false &&` would be enough to know that the expression is `false`.

I understand why the logic evaluates to `true`. What I do not understand is how this still satisfies short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Check presence and insert the brackets

Comment: "presence" == precedence, "brackets" == parentheses.  Well, that's one reason we don't program machines with natural language :)  One way to memorize the precedence is that & is equivalent to multiplication and | to addition when you count with two fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short circuit evaluation doesn't change the operator precedence. As the other answers pointed out, the expression is essentially `(false && false) || true`. Since the && operator is evaluated first, it'll skip evaluating the second false value (could have been `(false && _) || true`).

Then, we have a `false || true` expression which evaluates to `true`.

If the expression was `false && (_)`, your thought would have been correct.

Answer (score 2):

See the section under "Programming Languages" for this article on order of operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operation

Essentially, the `&&` operators execute first, before evaluating `||`. In your case, it doesn't matter what booleans you put in your `x && y` because the `|| true` will always make it true.

Comment: Can you explain why this does not conflict with short-circuit evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

Because `||` has lower precedence than `&&`. It evaluates as `(false && false) || true`; See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score -1):

false && false || true = (false && false) || true, hence, it is (anything OR true), which is, surely, true.